# Order by date in 'DD-MM-YYYY' format

Tags: android, sqlite, date, sql-order-by

I'm having problems to order by date. I'm storing date in a TEXT field at my datebase, when I try to order it doesn't bring me the right result.

Here is an example of a query that i have tried.

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnector.getDatabase().query(
                TABELA_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUNAS_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_PLUVIOMETRO_ID + " = " + pluviometroId,
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                "strftime('%Y-%m-%d', '" + COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO + "' )" );
```

I've tried to use the funcion "date(' + COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO  + "')", but it looks like it's ordering by date, but ASC or DESC doesn't work. It always bring me in the same order.

I know that I should store date as a integer, but I don't want to change it know and I want a solution like that. Any one can help? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Not working. I've tried those two ways:

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnector.getDatabase().query(
                TABELA_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUNAS_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_PLUVIOMETRO_ID + " = " + pluviometroId,
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                "date( " + COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO + " )" );
```

And with ''

```
Cursor cursor = databaseConnector.getDatabase().query(
                TABELA_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUNAS_PRECIPITACAO, 
                COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_PLUVIOMETRO_ID + " = " + pluviometroId,
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                "date( '" + COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO + "' )" );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from YourTable
Order by date(COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO)
```

or

```
Select * from YourTable
Order by datetime(COLUMN_PRECIPITACAO_DATA_PRECIPITACAO)
```

Comment: I have to use a rawQuery? Can't I use the query method? I've tried to use the date() in the query() and didn't work.

Comment: You can use the query method.  You're just running a sql statement.

Comment: You might have to use rawQuery()

Comment: I think that the problem is the format, because as I red the sqlite only accepts YYYY-MM-DD, so I'll try to convert it to that format before trying to use the date() method.

Answer (score 2):

`DD-MM-YYYY` is not one of the [supported formats](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html), so the `strftime` function (or `date`) always returns NULL.

Change your datebase to use the format `yyyy-mm-dd` (in which case you don't need to call any date function; just use the value directly for sorting).